# Deploying NextJS app on IIS web server not working

Tags: reactjs, iis, deployment, next.js, web-config

Hello so I've been tasked with deploying our next web app to a IIS windows server and cant see to figure out how to get passed this problem I am running into.

I just have a basic create-next-app with pretty much no code trying to get it deployed to the server and working correctly.

I've read around and it seems I'm running into a permissions issue but from a lot of reading I cant seem to figure out what I need to change

[image]

[image]

Here my web.config and server.js that are currently located in the root directory.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>


        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="node_modules"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
   <iisnode node_env="production" />
  
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

```js
const {createServer} = require('http');
const {parse} = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({dev});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const {pathname, query} = parsedUrl;

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query);
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query);
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLsx0iraA-Y

Comment: As the error message says, you need more information to solve your problem, you can use ETW traces or failed request tracing to get detailed information

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about NextJs but

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\hunte'

seems to indicate that the IIS process wants to access your user directory. With default IIS permissions the Application pool process has no permissions to access any user directories.

Do you have your application files under `C:\Users\hunte`,? move them somewhere else where the users group has read-permissions.

Also:

> HTTP subStatus: 1002

this doesn't look like an IIS subStatus, I've never a 1002.

Comment: I do, its currently just on my local machines desktop. I am fairly certain that what you are describing is the problem, I just dont know how to go from here because I've never used IIS until now.

Comment: I moved the whole project folder into C:/Users and it works now haha, Thanks a lot for the reply though!